# Clear a window once the dataSource stops pumping data

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

For example, I have a flink windowing application whose dataSource is a kafka stream sending employee names from different companies. Now if the dataSource from one company stops pumping data, I want clear all the data stored inside that window. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a Flink `WatermarkStrategy` that only emits a watermark when the source has been idle for "long enough", and then clear your state when that watermark triggers a timer.

Note that "long enough" has to account for things like operational issues where the topic is not receiving data due to an upstream issue, etc. So it's a bit dangerous to depend on this.